# Can I have an mvc3 area within an mvc2 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

Can I have an MVC3 area within an MVC2 app?

I already have an MVC2 app running and it has a lot of views, controllers, models, controls, etc. now, I need to add a new functionality that fits the requierments to be an MVC Area, but I want to make it using MVC3, and migrate all the app is not a posibility (for now).

So, I want to know if this aproach (MVC3 area inside MVC2 app) is possible, and if so, what I need to do it.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible, so many changes, a MVC2 Controller != MVC3 Controller, etc but I am also very interested in the answer if anyone has a workaround of any sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your code running on mvc3 first. I don't believe you can cross pollinate like you want. Hopefully your MVC2 code ports ok :)